# Redirect specific page via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter site and the problem is I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

But this results in people going from example.com to www.example.com/index.php/

I'd like them simply to go to www.example.com

Any ideas? Also, if they're at example.com/page1 they should go to www.example.com/page1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache is rewriting `/` to `/index.php/` before that rule is processed. Try moving it to the top of the file.